# How to display selected div values in another div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

On navigation of the Accordians and once we select the checkboxes , i need to display the 
Image , Checkbox selected value

Please see the jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/keVSJ/1/

I have written this , but somehow i am getting undefined error

```
 $(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  var HTML = ('<div id="mee">');
  HTML.append('<img type="img" height="40" width="40" src="'+$('#images').attr('src')+'"/>') ;
 HTML.append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+$(this).attr('value')+'" value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'"/>'+$(this).attr('desc')+"<br/>") ;

 var HTML = ('</div>');

}else{
       $('#mee').remove();
}
});
```

please see the picture here

[image]

Comment: where do you want to display this new div?

Comment: on top of the Accordian CoolDrinks in my case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `var HTML` two times, so need to remove that and take jQuery instance of `HTML` variable with `div` closed. As you said you want this to display above accordian then just prepend `HTML` to accordian `div`.

This is JQuery :

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) {

if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  var HTML = $('<div id="mee"></div>');
  HTML.append('<img type="img" height="40" width="40" src="'+$('#images').attr('src')+'"/>') ;
 HTML.append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+$(this).attr('value')+'" value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'"/>'+$(this).attr('desc')+"<br/>") ;
$("#fororders").prepend(HTML);
 //var HTML = ('</div>');

}else{
       $('#mee').remove();
}
});
```

Working JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/keVSJ/5/).

NOTE : checked checkbox desc shown as undefined.

Comment: This is what i was looking for , but why it is coming as undefined ??

Comment: and also if you check the resultant checkbox it is creating another checkbox .

Comment: because you have click event for checkbox and that can be any checkbox

Comment: I guess this is due to , $(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) { , Can i differentiate this function for the newly created checkbox??

Comment: yes you can add class="new" for newly created checkbox and then filter it on the basis of class

Comment: in that case should i use $(document).on("click", "#oldcheckboxid", function (e) {

Comment: yeah that you can use but instead of id you should use some class because two checkboxes cannot bear same id :)